# Hypercohomology and acyclicity of direct images

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-functors

Let $f: X\rightarrow Y$, $g:Y \rightarrow Z$ be  morphisms of topological spaces and let $K^{.}$ be an injective object in the category of complexes of abelian sheaves on $X$. Write $\mathbb R^0f_* K^.$ for the zeroth hyperderived image of this complex under $f$.

Then, why is $\mathbb R^0f_* K^.$ acyclic for the functor $g_*$ ?

Comment: For me this looks like a HW question, anyway why don't you add your effort about the problem here that will help others to guide you.

Comment: This is not HW. If the complex is just one sheaf, then the claim is clear because of flasqueness of the direct image. Yet, I don't see how to generalize to complexes.

Comment: add your argument in the question, that will help you to get better answers.